# Pyspark - Index from monotonically_increasing_id changes after list aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm creating an index using the `monotonically_increasing_id()` function in Pyspark 3.1.1.

I'm aware of the specific characteristics of that function, but they don't explain my issue.

After creating the index I do a simple aggregation applying the `collect_list()` function on the created index.

If I compare the results the index changes in certain cases, that is specifically on the upper end of the long-range when the input data is not too small.

Full example code:

```
import random
import string

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("test")\
    .master("local")\
    .config('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '8')\
    .getOrCreate()

# Create random input data of around length 100000:
input_data = []
ii = 0
while ii <= 100000:
    L = random.randint(1, 3)
    B = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=5))
    for i in range(L):
        C = random.randint(1,100)
        input_data.append((B,))
        ii += 1

# Create Spark DataFrame:
input_rdd = sc.parallelize(tuple(input_data))

schema = StructType([StructField("B", StringType())])
dg = spark.createDataFrame(input_rdd, schema=schema)

# Create id and aggregate:
dg = dg.sort("B").withColumn("ID0", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
dg2 = dg.groupBy("B").agg(f.collect_list("ID0"))

Output:
dg.sort('B', ascending=False).show(10, truncate=False)
dg2.sort('B', ascending=False).show(5, truncate=False)
```

This of course creates different data with every run, but if the length is large enough (problem appears slightly at 10000, but not at 1000), it should appear everytime. Here's an example result:

```
+-----+-----------+
|B    |ID0        |
+-----+-----------+
|ZZZVB|60129554616|
|ZZZVB|60129554617|
|ZZZVB|60129554615|
|ZZZUH|60129554614|
|ZZZRW|60129554612|
|ZZZRW|60129554613|
|ZZZNH|60129554611|
|ZZZNH|60129554609|
|ZZZNH|60129554610|
|ZZZJH|60129554606|
+-----+-----------+
only showing top 10 rows

+-----+---------------------------------------+
|B    |collect_list(ID0)                      |
+-----+---------------------------------------+
|ZZZVB|[60129554742, 60129554743, 60129554744]|
|ZZZUH|[60129554741]                          |
|ZZZRW|[60129554739, 60129554740]             |
|ZZZNH|[60129554736, 60129554737, 60129554738]|
|ZZZJH|[60129554733, 60129554734, 60129554735]|
+-----+---------------------------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

The entry `ZZZVB` has the three IDs `60129554615`, `60129554616`, and `60129554617` before aggregation, but after aggregation the numbers have changed to `60129554742`, `60129554743`, `60129554744`.

Why? I can't imagine this is supposed to happen. Isn't the result of `monotonically_increasing_id()` a simple long that keeps its value after having been created?

EDIT: As expected a workaround is to `coalesce(1)` the DataFrame before creating the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dg` and `df2` are two different dataframes, each with their own DAG. These DAGs are executed independently from each other when an action on one of the dataframes is called. So each time `show()` is called, the DAG of the respective dataframe is evaluated and during that evaluation, `f.monotonically_increasing_id()` is called.

To prevent `f.monotonically_increasing_id()` being called twice, you could add a [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html) after the `withColumn` transformation:

```python
dg = dg.sort("B").withColumn("ID0", f.monotonically_increasing_id()).cache()
```

With the cache, the result of the first evaluation of `f.monotonically_increasing_id()` is cached and reused when evaluating the second dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that clears up a lot of confusion.

Comment: How secure is that , what will happen in case of cache eviction , whats the safest way.

Comment: @sp_user123 Good point! I would hope that after cache eviction both dags would be reevaluated, but I am not too sure. At the moment I cannot find a good test scenario for this situation to find out what would happen. Maybe that's worth a new question?